# Showing the loading text while event is dispatched from the button in flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Bloc builder is not changing the ui while dispatching the event from the Inkwell onTap method.

Here is code:

```
BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => VendorsingleprofileBloc(
          RepositoryProvider.of<VendorRepository>(context)),
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            BlocBuilder<VendorsingleprofileBloc, VendorsingleprofileState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                print(state);
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: state is VendorFollowing
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          context
                              .read<VendorsingleprofileBloc>()
                              .add(VendorFollowing(vendorId));
                        },
                  child: Globalbutton(
                      height: 50,
                      width: heightandwidth(context)['width'] * .44,
                      text: state is VendorFollowing ? '...' : 'Follow',
                      paddingValue: 8.0),
                );
              },
            ),
```

I want to change the Follow text to ... when user tap the inkwell function.

The above function clearly dispatch the event and return data through the repository but doesnot change the my text.

Comment: Where does the value of `state is VendorFollowing` change?

Comment: it changes on on Tap method

Comment: Change `state` to `bloc provider`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you want.

use `setState` or `provider`

**use setState**

```
bool bState = false;

onTap: (){
  setState(() {
         bState = !bState;
       });
}


Globalbutton(
                      height: 50,
                      width: heightandwidth(context)['width'] * .44,
                      text: bState ? '...' : 'Follow',
                      paddingValue: 8.0),
                );
```

**user Provider**

```
onTap: (){
  context.read<your_class_name>().bState = !(context.read<your_class_name>().bState);
}


Globalbutton(
                      height: 50,
                      width: heightandwidth(context)['width'] * .44,
                      text: context.watch<youu_class_name>().bState ? '...' : 'Follow',
                      paddingValue: 8.0),
                );
```